# unable to filter on a specific string pattern and unable to change the index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

```
customer_data = 

Account ID         Account Name      Account Status       gb
1-ABC              ABC               Customer Active      90
2-XYZ              XYZ               Customer Inactive   100
1-CBA              CBA               Indirect - Active    50
2-GHC              GHC               Direct - Inactive    67
```

For

```
print(customer_data.dtypes)
```

Output is

```
gb    int64
dtype: object
```

For

```
print(customer_data.columns)
```

Output is

```
Index(['gb'], dtype='object')
```

I am trying to have two dataframes, one with those accounts which have text `Active` in `Account Status`and other those which have string `Inactive` in `Account Status`

I tried this 

`only_active = customer_data[customer_data['Account Status'].str.contains("Active")]`

and 

`only_inactive = customer_data[customer_data['Account Status'].str.contains('Inactive')]`

getting error like this

`KeyError: 'Account Status'`

Please help me on this, I want two dataframes, one with those accounts which have text `Active` in `Account Status`and other those which have string `Inactive` in `Account Status`

Comment: `'Account Status'` is not a column name in `customer_data` there is probably a lead or trailing white space

Comment: If your `.columns` only contains the entry `gb`, then you have the others in a multiindex. Try using `reset_index()` first

Comment: @G.Anderson Thanks a ton!, the resetting of index works and can the filter works and also I am able to successfully write them to excel.

Comment: Since it resolved your issue, I added detial and made an answer you can accept if you choose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dataframe looks like

```
Account ID | Account Name | Account Status | gb
```

but `customer_data.columns` only contains `['gb']`, then your other columns are in a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html) from some groupby or similar earlier in the code. To get those indices back as columns, you can use `customer_data.reset_index()`, then your columns will be usable in filtering without using index or multiindex methods

Comment: Can you please also help me how to I add the a string  like ``"Total is"``` and sum of the ``gb`` values to a new sheet in excel.

I tried ``Total = sum(only_active['gb'])`` and

``Total.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Summary', startcol=1,startrow=3, header=None)``

I get error as "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'to_excel'"

Comment: That sounds like a separate question but if you want to use the `to_excel` method, you need to call it on a datafraeme or series. So you could put the desired text output into a one-element series like `Total = pd.Series(["total is{}".format(sum(only_active['gb'])"])` and then the rest of your code, but beyond that guess I would try some things and then ask a new question with a new [mcve]